# How to search for the Nth match in a line in Vim?

Tags: search, vim, editor, match

I am editing a wiki file and would like to add a new column in between of two existing columns.

```
| *No* | *Issue* | *File* | *Status* | 
| 1 | blah | foo | open |
| 2 | blah1 | foo1 | close |
```

Say, I want to insert a new column between the 3rd and 4th columns above. If I could search for the fourth match of the `|` character in a given line, I could replace that with `| |`. But how one can do that in Vim?

The end result would look like so:

```
| *No* | *Issue* | *File* | | *Status* | 
| 1 | blah | foo | | open |
| 2 | blah1 | foo1 | | close |
```

Comment: how about using macro (`q`) to do that?

Answer (score 3):

How about recording a macro into register `q` by entering `qq3f|a|<ESC>q` in command mode (ESC means pressing the Escape key). Now you can apply this macro to each line by `:%norm@q`.

**Additional bonus:**

With this pattern you can add more complex actions, for example replicate the first column as column 3 (if cursor is at first column):

```
qqf yf|;;;p0q
```

Oh, and the answer to your question: Search 4th occurrence of `|` on a line is done by `3f|` (if the cursor is at position 0 and on a `|` character as in your example).

Comment: You can use `%` instead of `0,$`. Much nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following substitution command.

```
:%s/\%(.\{-}|\)\{4}\zs/ |/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
:%s/\(|[^|]*\)\{3\}/&| /
```

Which means: on each line (`%`), find three occurrences (`\{3\}`) of  a string that starts with | followed by any number of non-| (`[^|]*`), and replace that with itself (`&`) followed by `|`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `sed` in `vim` as a filter:

```
:%!sed 's/|/| |/4'
```